# Why does this work if strings are immutable?

Tags: python, string

For this code (python):

```
name = input("please enter your name")

introStatement = "please take a seat"

if name != "":

    introStatement = (name) + " please take a seat"

print(introStatement)
```

I was expecting a TypeError, but the program was able to print a given name and the intro statement, I thought that strings were immutable so we wouldn't be able to do this.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated, 
Thank you

Comment: You aren't modifying a string.  You are assigning a brand-new string to a variable.

Comment: In Python, the names of variables and functions are written in `lowercase_with_underscores` style not `camelCase`. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: Thank you Boris! I am new to programming so I really appreciate any feedback I can get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you aren't modifying the name or the original introStatement.

How Python works behind the hood is that it (sort of) creates a new "array" and copies "name" and " please have a seat" to the new array. Thus, the original string isn't amended, but rather, a new one is made.

Comment: There's no need to sneak the word "array" in here. The `+` operator creates a new string, full stop. The assignment make `introStatement` refer to that new string, regardless of what the name used to refer to.

Comment: Yeah, I was sort of assuming the OP was coming from other languages like C, where the copying is explicit, and not done by the language, thus I was explaining from that perspective.